# Динамический select Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular2

Как в Angular2 сделать динамические select-ы?
Т.е есть три селекта: страна, город, улица. При вводе в первый select 'страна' нужно, чтобы отправлялся запрос на сервер и в селект 'город' подгружался список городов относящийся к этой стране. То-же с улицей. Спасибо!

Comment: Приведите пример кода, который у вас получился, что конкретно у вас не получается? Отправлять запросы или заполнять списки или т.д.

Comment: Мне не понятна общика логика в целом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все крайне просто:

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let elem of elements">{{i}}</option>
</select>

onChange(elemValue) {
    console.log(elemValue);
    this.cityService.getCity(elemValue).subscribe(
        (data) => {
            const cityname = data.cityName;
            this.cityService.getStreets(cityname).subscribe(
                (streetData) => {
                    // где streetData твои улицы.
                } (error) => {
                   // error
                }
        } (error) => {
            // error
        }
    )
}
```

Где `elemValue` значение `select` а вместо `cityService` и `getCity` подставишь свое значение.

Comment: Спасибо! Т.е. для каждого значения города в  select нужно писать свой  else if , чтобы делать запрос на сервер за нужным списком городов?

Comment: Да ну нет, ты что, сейчас обновлю ответ покажу как

Comment: Я понял, а запрос на улицы одновременно с запросом на страну делать или подгружать их когда user выберет город ?

Comment: когда user подгружает город конечно же, сейчас обновлю ответ покажу как но с тебя `+` :)

Comment: А куда + ставить?)

Comment: Обновил ответ, смотри, `+` это стрелочка вверх)) хехе

Comment: Аа, так я это уже сделал)

Comment: Работает все как надо?)

Comment: Сейчас буду пробовать)

Comment: А какую модель формы лучше реализовывать? Реактивную или template driven?

Comment: Я всегда использую реактивную, и тебе советую.

Answer (score 1):

Собственно выглядеть должно примерно так:

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" [(ngModel)]="selectCountryId" (ngModelChange)="changeCountry($event)">
    <option [ngValue]="undefined" [textContent]="'Ничего не выбрано'"></option>
    <option *ngFor='let country of countries' [ngValue]="country.Id" [textContent]="country.Name"></option>
</select>
<select class="form-control input-sm" [(ngModel)]="selectCityId">
    <option [ngValue]="undefined" [textContent]="'Ничего не выбрано'"></option>
    <option *ngFor='let city of cities' [ngValue]="city.Id" [textContent]="city.Name"></option>
</select>
```

В контроллере:

```
changeCountry($event) {
    this.service.getCities(this.selectCountryId)
        .subscribe(result => {
            this.cities = result;
        })
}
```

Собственно логика следующая. С начала подгружаются данные по умолчанию. Список стран и список городов. Далее, как только происходит выбор страны, вызывается обработчик `changeCountry`. В нём отправляется запрос на бэк, где происходит фильтрация. Полученный список городов рендирится.

Comment: Спасибо большое!